# Difference between onMeasure, onLayout, OnGlobalLayoutListener

Tags: android

I am doing a very simple feature like adding ellipsis at the end of a TextView.

I could add the feature in onMeasure(), onLayout() and OnGlobalLayoutListener() call. But I really wanna know what's the difference by implementing the same functionality but in these three different method.
Are there any preferences or pros and cons for choosing these different implementation ways?

Thank you

Comment: Did you read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: Hi Eric, I actually read this document and it confused me more. After I read the doc, it makes me more confused. Like onMeasure would do the measure things, onLayout() would layout the children views, but OnGlobalLayoutListener() would be called after there is a layout change. So, my question is, where should my code for adding the ellipsis go? Because I can do this in all three functions, but I am really not sure where I should put my logic.

Answer (score 7):

Try to follow [this](http://www.jayway.com/2012/12/12/creating-custom-android-views-part-4-measuring-and-how-to-force-a-view-to-be-square/) it will help

> The layout process consists of two passes, measuring and layouting. A
>   bit simplified we can say that the measure pass sets how big the view
>   should be, the dimensions of it, and that the layout pass sets where
>   to place the view, the position of it. The layout part is only
>   interesting for views with children, in other words views that
>   inherits from ViewGroup.

Comment: The link is really useful, Must visit for all who are searching answer for this question